# SQL query to get the maximum dated row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query which is giving me multiple rows for different dates for an employee like -

```
PROCESSSTARTDATE  EMPLOYEENUMBER RUN_ACTION  CURRENTAMOUNT
10-JUL-2020          27             D           10
11-JUL-2020          27             C           10.3
12-JUL-2020          27             F           11.6

11-JUL-2020          28             C           2.8
12-JUL-2020          28             F           2
13-JUL-2020          28             G           11.6
```

Query used for above output-

```
Select pa.processstartdate,
paam.assignment_number EMPLOYEENUMBER,
pr.RUN_ACTION RUN_ACTION,
pa.CURRENTAMOUNT
from
per_all_actions pa,
per_all_assignments_m paam,
per_run pr
where pa.action_id = pr.action_id
and paam.assignment_id = pr.assignment_id
```

I want only the max PROCESSSTARTDATE rows from the output. i.e.

```
PROCESSSTARTDATE  EMPLOYEENUMBER RUN_ACTION  CURRENTAMOUNT
12-JUL-2020          27             F           11.6
13-JUL-2020          28             G           11.6
```

how to do that ?

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` format?

Comment: It's Oracle's proprietary join syntax.

Comment: Oracle implemented ANSI JOIN (standard) format in version 9i in 2001. But the format used is not  proprietary as other RDBMS also allow its use. But it is obsolete in all of then.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use aggregation with the `keep` keyword:

```
Select max(pa.processstartdate) as processstartdate,
       paam.assignment_number as EMPLOYEENUMBER,
       max(pr.RUN_ACTION) keep (dense_rank first order by pa.processstartdate desc) as RUN_ACTION,
       max(pa.CURRENTAMOUNT) keep (dense_rank first order by pa.processstartdate desc) as current_amount
from per_all_actions pa join
     per_run pr
     on pa.action_id = pr.action_id join
     per_all_assignments_m paam
     on paam.assignment_id = pr.assignment_id
group by paam.assignment_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rank` to get the lastest row per employee. As a side note, implicit joins (having more than one table in the `from` clause) are an outdated practice, and you should probably use explicit `join` clauses instead:

```sql
SELECT processstartdate, employeenumber, run_action, currentamount
FROM   (SELECT pa.processstartdate AS processstartdate,
               paam.assignment_number AS employeenumber,
               pr.run_action AS run_action,
               pa.currentamount AS currentamount,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY paam.assignment_number 
                            ORDER BY processstartdate DESC) AS rk
        FROM   per_all_actions pa
        JOIN   per_run pr ON pa.action_id = pr.action_id
        JOIN   per_all_assignments_m paam ON paam.assignment_id = pr.assignment_id) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a pseudo column using the row_number window clause, group by empployee and order by date descending.

then wrap that in a sub_query where you only see row_number=1.

something like:

```
select *
  from (select pa.processstartdate,
               paam.assignment_number EMPLOYEENUMBER,
               pr.RUN_ACTION RUN_ACTION,
               pa.CURRENTAMOUNT,
               row_number() over(partition by paam.assignment_number order by pa.processstartdate desc) as rn
          from per_all_actions pa, per_all_assignments_m paam, per_run pr
         where pa.action_id = pr.action_id
           and paam.assignment_id = pr.assignment_id) t
 where t.rn = 1
```